# How to predict multiple features using keras with time series?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a problem I don't know how to fix transform to add new features in order to make more proper forecast. The code below predicts stock prices by `Close` value. Data:

```
                             Open    High     Low   Close  Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                                                                     
2020-03-10 09:30:00+03:00  5033.0  5033.0  4690.0  4840.0     4840.0   702508
2020-03-10 10:30:00+03:00  4840.0  4870.0  4700.0  4746.5     4746.5  1300648
2020-03-10 11:30:00+03:00  4746.5  4783.0  4706.0  4745.5     4745.5  1156482
2020-03-10 12:30:00+03:00  4745.5  4884.0  4730.0  4870.0     4870.0  1213268
2020-03-10 13:30:00+03:00  4874.0  4990.5  4867.5  4886.5     4886.5  1958028
...                           ...     ...     ...     ...        ...      ...
2020-04-03 14:30:00+03:00  5177.0  5217.0  5164.0  5211.5     5211.5   385696
2020-04-03 15:30:00+03:00  5212.0  5364.0  5191.0  5269.5     5269.5  1091066
2020-04-03 16:30:00+03:00  5270.0  5297.0  5209.0  5220.5     5220.5   518686
2020-04-03 17:30:00+03:00  5222.0  5271.0  5184.0  5220.5     5220.5   665096
2020-04-03 18:30:00+03:00  5217.5  5223.5  5197.0  5204.5     5204.5   261400
```

I want to add `Volume` and `Open` features, but getting error:

```
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 436, in inverse_transform
    X -= self.min_
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (40,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (40,3)
```

**Q1:** How to change `inverse_transform` and what else do I need to change (`input_shape` argument maybe) to get correct results?

**Q2:** The result will be prediction of `Close` value. But how do I predict `Volume` value also? I guess I need to set `model.add(Dense(2))`, but can I do 2 predictions correctly in one code, or I need to execute script separately? How to do that? How do I get `Volume` than `Open` when `model.add(Dense(2))`?

Full code:

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yfinance as yf

start = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))
end = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=0))
df = yf.download(tickers="LKOH.ME", start=start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), end=end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), interval="60m")
df = df.loc[start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]

# I need here add another features
# df.filter(['Close', 'Open', 'Volume']) <-- this will make further an error with shapes
data = df.filter(['Close'])
dataset = data.values

#Get the number of rows to train the model on, 40 rows for test
training_data_len = len(dataset) - 40
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_data = scaled_data[0:int(training_data_len), :]
x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

model = Sequential()
# should i change to input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 3) ?
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)


test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60: , :]
x_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])


x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1 ))
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions) # error here
```

Comment: Code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue, adds unnecessary clutter, and should not be included (edited out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are fitting `MinMaxScaler` on `dataset`, then splitting `dataset` into `x_train` and `y_train` and then later on trying to use the `inverse_transform` method on the predictions, which have the same shape as `y_train`.  I suggest you create `x_train` and `y_train` and fit `MinMaxScaler` only to `x_train`.  `y_train` doesn't need to be scaled for the model and that will save you needing to `inverse_transform` the predictions completely.

So instead of

```
#Get the number of rows to train the model on, 40 rows for test
training_data_len = len(dataset) - 40
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_data = scaled_data[0:int(training_data_len), :]
x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```

Use

```
#Get the number of rows to train the model on, 40 rows for test
training_data_len = len(dataset) - 40
train_data = scaled_data[0:int(training_data_len), :]
x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)  # Only scaling x_train

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```

and just delete the line `predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)`.

#### Updates relating to additional questions in the comments

The definition of `y_test` is inconsistent with `y_train`.  Specifically, `y_test` is defined as `y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]` which is using all of the columns of `dataset`.  Instead, to be consistent with `y_train`, it should be `dataset[training_data_len:, 0]`.

Handling splitting the data is often clearer and less error-prone if done in `pandas`:

```
# Starting with the dataframe 'data'
data = df.filter(['Close', 'Open', 'Volume'])

# Create x/y test/train directly from 'data'
training_data_len = len(data) - 40
x_train = data[['Open', 'Volume']][:training_data_len]
y_train = data.Close[:training_data_len]
x_test = data[['Open', 'Volume']][training_data_len:]
y_test = data.Close[training_data_len:]

# Then confirm you have the expected subsets by checking things like
# shape (and info(), describe(), etc.)
x_train.shape, x_test.shape
> ((160, 2), (40, 2))

y_train.shape, y_test.shape
> ((160,), (40,))
```

Comment: Correct. In addition, `x_test` need to be scaled with `scaler.transform(x_test)` before used for predictions. If for whatever reason the outputs `y` need also to be scaled, a separate scaler should be used.

Comment: @desertnaut @Chris almost there, I changed as you said (no `y_train` fitting) and added `x_test = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)` before `predictions = model.predict(x_test)`, but predictions are small, the `rmse=4901.79`. Why is that if we didn't scaled `y_train`?

Comment: Also I noticed when I added 3 features to `train_data` (`Open`, `Close` and `Volume`), when I do `x_train` in loop `for i in range(60, len(train_data)): x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])`, there is no `Volume` in `x_train` var, so it's like `Volume` feature loses. How to take it into account?

Comment: @sirjay I've added an edit which addresses one issue in the code.  Why the predictions are small is another matter and, therefore, question.  As the input data has changed, and because it's possible there are errors elsewhere in your code, it would be better to ask a new question which includes all of the relevant code.

Comment: The reason `Volume` is missing is because your indexing column `0`. `x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])` should have `[1:]` as the column index, so that `x_train` gets all the features except `close`.

Comment: Personally, I like to stay in `pandas` for this sort of manipulation, for exactly these reasons – it's much clearer when you can select columns by name.  E.g. `y_train = dataset.close`.

Comment: Chris, thank you for help, still can't get it. The code in my question works, compiles and shows good prediction. But when I change it (no scaling y_train) even without adding new features (Open and Volume), it predicts wrong. I think I will make question eligible for bounty, maybe someone will compile code to check it.

Comment: @sirjay let me kindly remind that the scope of the original question was (is) the error, and this has been successfully addressed by the answer. Asking follow-up questions in the comments regarding different issues downstream is neither productive nor how SO really works. I suggest you accept the answer and, as already suggested, open a new one with the specifics of your new situation after the error has been resolved.